# In Visual Studio 2010, is there a way to keep recently-used files from falling off the File Tab Channel?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

In Visual Studio 2008 you could use [Sara Ford's did you know #331](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/saraford/archive/2008/10/09/did-you-know-you-can-keep-recently-used-files-from-falling-off-the-file-tab-channel-331.aspx) ([Did you know… You can keep recently-used files from falling off the File Tab Channel? - #331](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/saraford/archive/2008/10/09/did-you-know-you-can-keep-recently-used-files-from-falling-off-the-file-tab-channel-331.aspx)) to make the tabs ordered in MRU (most recently used) order (i.e. the current window is always the left most tab, the previously visited window is second tab, and so forth).

The registry entry listed in the blog post does not appear to work in VS2010 and I have not figured out a way to get tabs listed in MRU.  Does anyone know if there is a way in Visual Studio 2010 to keep the most recently-used file from falling off the File Tab Channel?

Answer (score 1):

In the "Productivity Power Tools" extension, the [Remove Tabs By Usage Order](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/document-well-2010-plus-hidden-options/#lru) option seems to be what you are looking for.

Comment: Not quite because I want the most recently used document to appear on the left always.  This will leave the documents where they are and then just remove one if it does not fit.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing the ["Productivity Power Tools" extension](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/d0d33361-18e2-46c0-8ff2-4adea1e34fef) - you can disable any other features that you don't use, but the customisation of the tab well is very useful.  I don't think it does MRU order, but there are a number of other options that might help.

Comment: I tried the "Productivity Power Tools" extension and can customize the tab well a bunch (and maybe I will like it better in the future) but it does not seem to support MRU order (at least I could not find it) and that is really what I want.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution, if you are using Windows 7, would be to pin VS2010 to the task bar and then pin them to the programme tasks bar within that through drag and drop for instance.

Comment: But that would mean I would have to do something each time I open a document which is not what I want... I just want the most recently used file to show up on the left hand side of the tab well (and not require me to do some other action).  Also the "Productivity Power Tools" extension as mentioned in Dan Puzey's answer lets you pin files (but that is not exactly what I want).

Comment: Well, it's still a solution. It just involves a few more clicks than you want and the implementation is slightly different. I suppose you could always write an extension for VS2010.